# $\int_0^\infty |2 \arctan\sqrt{x} - \pi {x^p}/(1+x^p)| \mathrm dx $

Tags: integration, limits, hypergeometric-function

Let $a(x) = 2 \arctan\sqrt{x}$ and $b(x) = \pi {x^p}/(1+x^p)$. I'm trying to evaluate:

$$\int_0^\infty |a(x) - b(x)| \mathrm dx $$

I've figured out I need the integrals:

$$\int_0^1 a(x)-b(x) dx = \left[A(x)-B(x)\right]_0^1$$ and
$$\int_1^\infty a(x)-b(x) dx = \left[A(x)-B(x)\right]_1^\infty$$

The first of which is finite, but the second may or may not be. $A(x)$ has an expression in terms of elementary functions:

$$A(x) = (1+x)\arctan{\sqrt{x}} - \sqrt{x}$$

But $B$ is not so nice. Wolfram Alpha gives a result in terms of the hypergeometric function:

$$B(x) = x\left(1-{}_2F_1\left[1,\frac{1}{p};1+\frac{1}{p}; -x^p\right]\right)$$

Evaluation of some things are easy $A(0)=B(0)=0$, $A(1)=\pi/2 - 1$ and $B(1)$ has an expression.

So, basically I need to know if

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} A(x)-B(x)$$

converges, and if so, to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Taylor series for $\arctan x$ at $x=\infty$, we find
$$A(x) = \frac{\pi x}{2}-2 \sqrt{x} +o(1).$$

As you mention, the $B(x)$ term is more ornery. Our limit depends fundamentally on the sign of $p$, which forces us to address $B(x)$ in cases.  Our first two are easy:

1. If $p=0$, then $B(x)=\pi x/2$ exactly, hence
   $$A(x)-B(x) = -2\sqrt{x}+o(1).$$
2. If $p<0$, we compute
   $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \,_2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{p},1+\frac{1}{p};-x^p\right)=\,_2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{p},1+\frac{1}{p};0\right)=1,$$
   in which we make use of the series definition for the hypergeometric function.  It follows that $B(x)=o(x)$, hence $A(x)-B(x)=\pi x/2 +o(x)$.
3. If $p>0$, our task is considerably harder.  Nevertheless, we claim that $B(x) \sim x$ as $x \to \infty$, i.e. that
   $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\,_2 F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{p},1+\frac{1}{p};-x^p\right)=\lim_{x \to \infty} \,_2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{p},1+\frac{1}{p};-x\right)=0.$$
   For $p>1$, write
   $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \,_2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{p},1+\frac{1}{p};-x\right)=\lim_{x \to \infty}(1+x)^{-1/p}\,_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{p},\frac{1}{p},1+\frac{1}{p};\frac{x}{1+x}\right)$$
   by [Euler's hypergeometric transformations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHypergeometricTransformations.html).  Our hypothesis $p>1$ allows us to apply [Gauss's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Special_values_at_z.C2.A0.3D.C2.A01), and we find
   $$_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{p},\frac{1}{p},1+\frac{1}{p},1\right)=\frac{\pi}{p} \csc\left(\frac{\pi}{p}\right).$$
   Therefore our claim holds because $(1+x)^{-1/p} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. If $p=1$ exactly, then
   $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \,_2 F_1\left(1,1,2;-x\right)=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=0,$$
   and our claim still holds.  Finally, given $p \in (0,1)$, Euler's hypergeometric relations give
   $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \,_2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{p},1+\frac{1}{p};-x\right)=\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+x)^{-1} \,_2F_1\left(1,1,1+\frac{1}{p};\frac{x}{1+x}\right).$$
   Fix $t \in \mathbb{R}$.  By definition,
   $$_2 F_1(1,1,t,x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-t}{k}^{-1}x^k,$$
   which converges at $x=1$ provided $t>2$.  In particular, setting $t=1+1/p$, we obtain a convergent sum at $x=1$, so that the value $_2F_1(1,1,1+1/p;1)$ is finite by [Abel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem).  It follows that
   $$\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+x)^{-1} \,_2F_1\left(1,1,1+\frac{1}{p};\frac{x}{1+x}\right)=0,$$
   again in accordance with our claim $B(x) \sim x$.  Thus $p >0$ implies
   $$A(x)-B(x) = \left(\frac{\pi}{2} -1 \right)x + o(1).$$

In conclusion, the limit
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} A(x)-B(x)$$
diverges, for **any** choice of $p \in \mathbb{R}$.

*Note: the weaker result $A(x) \sim B(x)$ holds if and only if $p=0$.*

Comment: Nice, very clear, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since $\arctan u+\arctan1/u=\pi/2$ for every positive $u$, 
$$
a(x)-b(x)=\frac{\pi}{1+x^p}-2\arctan\frac1{\sqrt{x}}.
$$
Let us look at the behaviour of $a(x)-b(x)$ when $x\to+\infty$::

- If $p\gt1/2$, the $\arctan$ term is predominant and  $\arctan1/\sqrt{x}\sim1/\sqrt{x}$ which is not integrable, hence $a-b$ is not integrable.
- If $p\lt1/2$, the $\pi/(1+x^p)$ term is predominant and $\pi/(1+x^p)\sim\pi/x^p$ when $p\gt0$ which is not integrable, hence $a-b$ is not integrable (when $p\leqslant0$, $\pi/(1+x^p)$ converges to a nonzero limit hence $a-b$ is not integrable either).
- If $p=1/2$, both terms are equivalent to multiples of $1/\sqrt{x}$ and $a(x)-b(x)\sim(\pi-2)/\sqrt{x}$ hence $a-b$ is not integrable.

Finally, the function $a-b$ is never integrable at $+\infty$.

**Tools used:**

- $\arctan u+\arctan1/u=\pi/2$ for $u\gt0$
- $u/(1+u)=1-1/(1+u)$ for every $u\ne-1$
- $1/(1+u)\sim1/u$ when $u\to\infty$
- $\arctan u\sim u$ when $u\to0$
- Integrability or nonintegrability of $u\mapsto u^a$ at $+\infty$, for various exponents $a$
- **NOT** W|A and **NO** hypergeometric function

Comment: I've found this useful for a related problem, finding the asymptotic minimising value of p.

Comment: Understand your comment I cannot. Rather surprised I am.

Comment: My comment said two things. Firstly, I am not considering this problem in isolation from other problems. Although I found the other answer more useful for the problem I was tackling at the time, I found the way of tackling the problem presented here was for one of the related problems. Secondly, that the problem that it was useful for concerned finding the value of $p$ that minimises the integral I presented above. i.e. Finding ($\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \arg\,\min_p \int_0^x \cdots$). Hope this is clearer.